# XPages - why are Dojo Filtering Select controls obligatory? Can they be customised?

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-notes

I am using some Dojo Filtering Select controls on my XPage. Despite having set the required property to false, when I attempt to save the XPage document, I see the message "This value is required" in the Dojo Filtering Select control. I would like to know

1/ is it possible to make a Dojo Filtering Select control NOT obligatory?

2/ Is it possible to customize the error message which appears when the control is obligatory?

Comment: I'm now trying to get client side validation working with a Dojo Filtering Select, however it just does not work :-( I have added my code to the question above.

Comment: The original question was answered. Your Update question is different from your first question. Why don't you create a new question?

Comment: Ok, I will do that. - Just created the new question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You get the message "This value is required" at client side validation. So, in addition to property `required="false"` which is responsible for server side validation only you have to set a dojoAttribute "required" to "false". Then you don't get the message anymore.

```xml
<xe:djFilteringSelect
    id="djFilteringSelect1"
    value="#{...}"
    required="false">
    <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute
            name="required"
            value="false">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
</xe:djFilteringSelect>
```

2) The same way you can set the dojoAttribute "missingMessage" to the string you like in case your control stays obligatory.

Comment: Thanks very much for this great solution. I only wish I were better at reading the Dojo documentation :-(

Answer (score 2):

you can customized these parameters (They are in the parent ValidationTextBox of FilteringSelect):

```
// required: Boolean
//      User is required to enter data into this field.
required: false,

// promptMessage: String
//      If defined, display this hint string immediately on focus to the textbox, if empty.
//      Also displays if the textbox value is Incomplete (not yet valid but will be with additional input).
//      Think of this like a tooltip that tells the user what to do, not an error message
//      that tells the user what they've done wrong.
//
//      Message disappears when user starts typing.
promptMessage: "",

// invalidMessage: String
//      The message to display if value is invalid.
//      The translated string value is read from the message file by default.
//      Set to "" to use the promptMessage instead.
invalidMessage: "$_unset_$",

// missingMessage: String
//      The message to display if value is empty and the field is required.
//      The translated string value is read from the message file by default.
//      Set to "" to use the invalidMessage instead.
missingMessage: "$_unset_$",

// message: String
//      Currently error/prompt message.
//      When using the default tooltip implementation, this will only be
//      displayed when the field is focused.
message: "",
```

If you set required to false, it should not prompt message, can you post you code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this helpful information! How did you find out that ValidationTextBox is the parent of FilteringSelect?